# What should I use to Listen for incoming calls services in Android or work manager of Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-workmanager

I am developing an application that needs to monitor incoming calls continuously, even when the app is not active. Initially, I implemented this functionality using broadcast receivers and services in Android. I'm confused about how the work manager can be used to listen to incoming calls all the time in the background, even if the app is not running.

I implemented the feature to listen to incoming calls all the time, even if the app is not running through services and broadcast receivers in Android.

Comment: `WorkManager` is not designed for your scenario.

Comment: So, the only option that remains is Services.